# Which are before vs which before

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

> It took about six years for airlines to recover capacity after the
> 9/11 terrorist attacks, **which before** the COVID-19 crisis, caused the
> steepest historic decline in air traffic.
>
> It took about six years for airlines to recover capacity after the
> 9/11 terrorist attacks, **which are before** the COVID-19 crisis, caused
> the steepest historic decline in air traffic.

The original sentence is the first one, I think the omission of "are" makes the first sentence gramatically wrong. I think the second sentence that I rewrote is the only correct one. Am I right ?

Comment: Adding *are* as you suggest makes the sentence wrong.

Comment: You are quite wrong. The sentence makes no sense with the addition of _are_.

Comment: @Peter Could you tell me the reasons why my rewrite is wrong ?

Comment: @KateBunting Could you tell me the reasons why my rewrite is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comma should be after *which*, not after *attacks.*

> It took about six years for airlines to recover capacity after the
> 9/11 terrorist attacks which, before the COVID-19 crisis, caused the
> steepest historic decline in air traffic.

Until the Covid-19 crisis, the steepest decline in air traffic that had ever happened was the one that was caused by the 9/11 attacks. *Which* refers to the attacks, and *before the Covid-19 crisis* is a parenthetical phrase - that is, it could be written in brackets, and the sentence would make sense without it.

Comment: Thanks Kate, you are so professional !

Comment: The comma before "which" is required. Without it, the which-clause becomes a *defining relative clause* specifying which 9/11 terrorist attacks we're talking about -- the ones that caused the steepest historic decline in air traffic.

Comment: Also, "before the COVID-19 crisis" isn't parenthetical. The sentence is factually incorrect with out it. Rather, it *interrupts* the relative clause, and so requires commas to separate it out.

Comment: @gotube -  OK - I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Peter and Kate in the comments are correct, the addition of "are" is incorrect.

If we look at the original sentence (with the comma placement fixed)

> It took about six years for airlines to recover capacity after the 9/11 terrorist attacks which, before the COVID-19 crisis, caused the steepest historic decline in air traffic.

This sentence is saying that before the COVID-19 crisis happened, the 9/11 attacks had caused the steepest decline in air traffic. The COVID-19 crisis caused a larger decline in air traffic than 9/11 did.

Here's another example of a "which, before X, " sentence structure to illustrate what it's trying to convey:

> I scored 1 million points in Tetris yesterday, which, before 2015, would have been a world record.

This is saying that my score of 1 million points would have been the world record in 2014, but in 2015 and beyond it wouldn't have - presumably the world record became larger than 1 million points in 2015.

Your suggested sentence with "are" is grammatically incorrect:

> It took about six years for airlines to recover capacity after the 9/11 terrorist attacks, which *are* before the COVID-19 crisis, caused the steepest historic decline in air traffic.

I think you might be attempting this sentence structure (apologies if I am incorrect), with "are" swapped with "were" to fix the tense, and an "and" added to connect the clauses, which would make your sentence more readable:

> It took about six years for airlines to recover capacity after the 9/11 terrorist attacks, which *were* before the COVID-19 crisis *and* caused the steepest historic decline in air traffic.

This sentence is semantically different from the first one. Instead of comparing the amount of air traffic decline, it just includes a clause saying that the 9/11 attacks happened before COVID-19, and incorrectly says that 9/11 caused the steepest historic decline in air traffic. This is not what the writer is trying to convey.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I have gotten a deeper understanding into how it works. The sentence structure you attempted to rewrite is exactly the one I want.
I still get another question :
Could I rewrite your example sentence to "I scored 1 million points in Tetris yesterday which, before 2015, would have been a world record." or  "I scored 1 million points in Tetris yesterday, which before 2015, would have been a world record." ?

Comment: @baktbd You need both commas.

Comment: @gotube what else will change if I omitted the comma like  "I scored 1 million points in Tetris yesterday which, before 2015, would have been a world record."